# UNIX_TIMESTAMP mysql query error

Tags: mysql, unix-timestamp

I'm trying to make a query using `UNIX_TIMESTAMP`, basicly this is my query:

`"SELECT * FROM payment WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(pay_till) >=".$today`

That's a pretty simple query, pay_till has the value 2016-09-21 23:59:59, & today is 1474498800.

So it shouldn't return me any payment done after 2016-09-21 23:59:59, but some how it still return me payments till 2 days after.

Comment: *If UNIX_TIMESTAMP() is called with a date argument, The server interprets date as a value in the current time zone and converts it to an internal value in UTC* [from the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp)

Comment: Can you show some SQL columns of data and example the problem?

Comment: `2016-09-21 23:59:59` is a local time so there's no way to compare it with a Unix timestamp (`1474498800` in this case, which is `2016-09-21 23:00:00 UTC`) unless you know the time zone it belongs to. If you don't set it yourself, MySQL Server will assume whatever time zone is configured as default. However, there's no explanation for a two day error. Are you sure your diagnostic is correct? What happens when you print actual values in the `SELECT` clause so you can see them?